# Stop a Kafka Streams app

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to have a Kafka Streams app that runs through all the data in a topic and then exits?

Example I'm producing data into topics based on date. The consumer gets kicked off by cron, runs through all the available data and then .. does what? I don't want it to sit and wait for more data. Just assume it's all there and then exit gracefully.

Possible?

Comment: `I don't want it to sit and wait for more data`. Isn't that the very concept of a stream ? You're talking about batch scheduling, not streaming.

Comment: I am a little confuse why you accepted the answer below. If we talk about Kafka Streams library, the consumer is managed internally and you cannot access it... So how should the below shown method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `consumer` and then once it stops pulling up data, you can have call `consumer.close()`. Or if you want to poll again in the future just call `consumer.pause()` and call `.resume` later.

One way to do this is within the consumer poll block. Such as

```
data = consumer.poll()
if (!data.next()) {
   consumer.close()
}
```

Keep in mind that `poll` returns `ConsumerRecord<K,V>` and conforms to the `Iterable` interface.

Comment: This approach won't work for a Kafka Streams app as mentioned by Matthias J. Sax' comment to the question above.

Comment: This is a NON answer as the OP clearly asks for a Kafka Streams solution. Please delete your answer.

Answer (score 6):

In Kafka Streams (as for other stream processing solutions), the is no "end of data" because it is stream processing in the first place -- and not batch processing.

Nevertheless, you could watch the "lag" of your Kafka Streams application and shut it down if there is not lag (lag, is the number of not yet consumed messages).

For example, you can use `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to check the lag of your Streams application (the application ID is used as consumer group ID). If you want to embed this in your Streams applications, you can use `kafka.admin.AdminClient` to get consumer group information.